# Access denied to C:\Users\Public\Desktop

Tags: windows, permissions

I'm trying to install [an application](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/bundles/komplete-10/) which installs several programs and tries to write their shortcuts to C:\Users\Public\Desktop

It fails, saying that the access is denied, and then doesn't install the programs.

When I try to open C:\Users\Public\Desktop with Explorer, I also get access denied, although my Windows account is an admin account.

I'm using Windows 8.1 64 bits. UAC is set to the minimum setting. Starting the installation program or Explorer as administrator didn't help.

The Desktop folder is set to read only, but if I try to remove that, I get access denied as well. In Properties / Security / Advanced / Permissions, I can only see "You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings.".

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved, but I'm still not sure what caused it.

I restarted the computer in safe mode to try to access that "Desktop" folder, and it was not there anymore! Instead, there was a "Public Desktop" folder, which I could access without issues.
I rebooted the PC in normal mode, and same thing: "Desktop" has been replaced by "Public Desktop".

So I tried to install Komplete again, and this time it worked without issues. The programs shortcuts were created inside "Public Desktop".

Comment: "Desktop" changed to "Public Desktop"? It is the signature of Windows Update. More like the sign or her passage.

Comment: I can confirm that a restart solves this issue. The correct path is `C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop`, not sure how it changes on a restart.

Comment: I'm not sure how it happened, but while I was installing a `.msi` file on Windows server, I got the same error, and a simple `shutdown -r -t 0` to restart fixed this for me.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to get around this installation roadblock (in Windows 10 Home) by using the built-in administrator account to take ownership of this folder (or C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop, which seems to be the same as C:\Users\Public\Desktop), and then granting myself (and my everyday user profile) full permissions.  Weird glitch.  The install programs should just let you skip creating these shortcuts if you don't need them.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to resolve your issue, however you're working with a different version of Windows and so while your information is good to hear, it is not actually an answer to this question. SU is not a forum where open discussion is the purpose. SU is a site where specific questions can meet specific answers. Stick around. If you have a question, ask it. If you have an answer, give it (even on your own question, that's perfectly acceptable).